# How to modify a record in selected excel data sheet using VBA when there are multiple data sheets

Tags: excel

I have a data entry form and multiple data sheets named as Table1 and Table2.I want to modify data in a particular row in the selected datasheet using data entry form. In the data entry form, there are two buttons called SAVE and MODIFY buttons. First there is a option to select a table that I want to save data. Then I click modify button and it asks us to enter the serial number to make the modification. When I enter serial no of particular row in selected data sheet, all the details of that particular row should be appeared on the data entry form to modify and save it to the same row using SAVE button. But it gives a error mentioning that "no record found" and it cannot detect the selection of datasheets. The VBA code that I have used for MODIFY button is given below. Please help me solve this problem sir.

Sub ModifyRecord()
Dim shTable As Worksheet
Dim shForm As Worksheet
Dim iCurrentRow As Integer
Dim sTableName As String

```
Set shForm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form")    
sTableName = shForm.Range("H7").Value    
Set shTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sTableName)    
Dim irow As Long
Dim iSerial As Long
iSerial = Application.InputBox("Please enter Serial Number to make 
modification.", "Modify", , , , , , 1)

On Error Resume Next    
irow = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError _
(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(iSerial, 
Sheets("sTableName").Range("A:A"), 0), 0)

On Error GoTo 0

If irow = 0 Then   
    MsgBox "No record found.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Record"
    Exit Sub        
End If  
Sheets("Form").Range("L1").Value = irow
Sheets("Form").Range("M1").Value = iSerial    
Sheets("Form").Range("H9").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
2).Value    
Sheets("Form").Range("H11").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
3).Value  
Sheets("Form").Range("H13").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
4).Value    
Sheets("Form").Range("H15").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
5).Value   
Sheets("Form").Range("H17").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
6).Value    
Sheets("Form").Range("H19").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
7).Value     
Sheets("Form").Range("H21").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
8).Value    
Sheets("Form").Range("H23").Value = Sheets("sTableName").Cells(irow, _
9).Value
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you checked the variable `sTableName` so that `irow` gets set properly?

Comment: when I use "Table1" instead of sTableName it gives only the details of Table1.When I use "Table2" instead sTableName it gives only the details of Table2. But I want to do the selection of Tables.so what should be the code to select a data sheet. please answer sir.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Right now `sTabelName` is set to `shForm.Range("H7").Value` whatever that is. What do you mean by "selection"? Multiple tables, a physically selected one or something else?

Comment: when I have  multiple tables, what should be the code to select one table table and modify data

Comment: You say that there is an option to select tables, does that means sheets? What does it do? Does it modivy the value of `shForm.Range("H7")` because that seems to be the way you currently "select" what sheet to use.

Comment: yes sheets. I have named sheets as Table1 and Table2. First I have to select a data sheet from the option  in the data entry form and then I have to click the modify button to select a row and  make row details  appear in the data entry form to modify and save. But a error is coming that "no record found". I just want to select a data sheet and make a particular row details in selected worksheet  appear in the data entry form using modify button. how to avoid that error and do this task. what should be the code